# Groupby existing attribute present in json string line in apache beam java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am reading json files from GCS and I have to load data into different BigQuery tables. These file may have multiple records for same customer with different timestamp. I have to pick latest among them for each customer. I am planning  to achieve as below

1. Read files
2. Group by customer id
3. Apply DoFn to compare timestamp of records in each group and have only latest one from them
4. Flat it, convert to table row insert into BQ.

But I am unable to proceed with step 1. I see `GroupByKey.create()` but unable to make it use customer id as key.

I am implementing using JAVA. Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you `GroupByKey` you need to have your dataset in key-value pairs. It would be good if you had shown some of your code, but without knowing much, you'd do the following:

```java
PCollection<JsonObject> objects = p.apply(FileIO.read(....)).apply(FormatData...)

// Once we have the data in JsonObjects, we key by customer ID:
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<JsonObject>>> groupedData = 
     objects.apply(MapElements.via(elm -> KV.of(elm.getString("customerId"), elm)))
            .apply(GroupByKey.create())
```

Once that's done, you can check timestamps and discard all bot the most recent as you were thinking.

Note that you will need to set coders, etc - if you get stuck with that we can iterate.

As a hint / tip, you can consider [this example of a Json Coder](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/healthcare/JsonArrayCoder.java).

Comment: Thanks Pablo. with help of above code snippet now I managed like below 
`pipeline.apply("Read", TextIO.read().from(""))
.apply("", MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<String, KV<String, String>>() {@Override
public KV<String, String> apply(String json) {
JSONObject customerJson = new JSONObject(json);
return KV.of(customerJson.getString("_id"), customerJson.toString());}}))
.apply(GroupByKey.create())
.apply("Find latest in grp",MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<KV<String, Iterable<String>>, String>() {@Override
public String apply(KV<String, Iterable<String>> groupedElements) {}}));`

Comment: Though I was getting below error when while using JSONObject `org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<java.lang.String, org.json.JSONObject>: Unable to provide a Coder for org.json.JSONObject`.
so for now using toString() but we have to do json/string/json conversion at two places. How we can have our custom Coder to get rid of this

Comment: Here's an example of a JSON coder that returns a JsonArray - you would do the same, but with JsonObject: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/healthcare/JsonArrayCoder.java

Comment: I tried creating similar for JSONObject and using before group by step like `.setCoder(JSONObjectCoder.of()) .apply("Group by key -> customer id", GroupByKey.<String, JSONObject>create())` but getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: GroupByKey requires its input to use KvCoder`

Comment: Have you tried a KVCoder.of(StrUtf8Coder.of(), JsonObjectCoder.of()) ?